# When updating store, I get following error: NSUnderlyingException = "Cannot update object that was never inserted."

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

MY core data objects are following:

> Author (name) >> Book(title) >> Notes(text, dateOfNote)
>
> Relation boksByAuthor >> notesOnBook

```
+(void)persistBooksToDisk:(NSManagedObjectContext *)workerContext
                 subClass:(EECoreStack*)eeCoreStack
                  fromURL:(NSURL*)fileURL{
[workerContext performBlock:^{
        NSArray * array = [AP_TextExtract componentSeperatedByBooksFromTXTFile:fileURL];
        for (NSString *body in array) {
Note *note = (Note *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:workerContext];

note.dateOfNote = [AP_TextExtract dateOfNoteFromString:body];
note.text = [AP_TextExtract noteTextFromString:body];

 Book *book = (Book *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:workerContext];
            book.title = [AP_TextExtract bookNameFromString:body];
[book addNotesInBook: note];
  Author *author = (Author*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Author" inManagedObjectContext:workerContext];
            author.name = [AP_TextExtract authorNameFromString:body];
[author addBooksByAuthor: book];
}];

[eeCoreStack saveTemporaryWorkerContext:workerContext];
}
```

**saveTemporaryContext:**

```
- (void)saveTemporaryWorkerContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
[context performBlock:^{
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR SAVING TEMPORARY WORKER MOC %@:  %@:", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    }else {

        [self saveMainContext];
    }

}];
}

- (void)saveMainContext {
    [self.mainContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.mainContext save:&error];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"ERROR SAVING MAIN MOC %@: %@:", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        }else {
            [self saveMasterContext];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)saveMasterContext {

    [self.masterContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.masterContext save:&error];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"ERROR SAVING MASTER CONTEXT %@; : %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"doneSavingMasterContext" object:nil];

}
```

**The data is saved from Text File and saving follows pattern:**

> workerContext > mainContext > masterContext (Store)

First time data is saved successfully but later when it tries to save updated text file (**with only change in note text**), it throws out following error:

ERROR SAVING MASTER CONTEXT An error occurred while saving.

```
; : {   
 NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey =     (
            "<Note: 0x6000002d6570> (entity: Note; id: 0x600001424480 <x-coredata:///Note/t2371834C-1581-4A68-A56E-77E734B276CC1244> ; data:
    text = \"quitely right );
        NSUnderlyingException = "Cannot update object that was never inserted.";
    }
```

One thing I noticed that after restarting app, the data is saved but again start to give same error after that.

Edit 1: this error only show if, I update existing attribute, not if I insert new instance of attribute.

Answer (score 0):

When you are updating the data, first fetch the core data object using `NSFetchRequest` and then update the necessary data. Then make an attempt to save. You might be trying to update the data without fetching.